# How to capture WhatsApp web-client communication?

Tags: http, firefox, https, websocket, whatsapp

I am trying to know how WhatsApp web-client communicates

I am using WhatsApp app on my Android mobile phone and using
Firefox 56 on Windows 7 desktop for web-client

In Firefox I have opened https://web.whatsapp.com/ , scanned the
QR in my mobile, completed initial hand-shake and started using
WhatsApp web-client

In Firefox I opened Network Monitor tool to view the network
communication of the WhatsApp web-client, I sent a message from
my mobile app to one of my friends, the message gets reflected
in the web-client instantly but I don't see any entry in the
Network Monitor tool

How does WhatsApp web-client communicate with the server or the
mobile app, how to capture the communication

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Related newer question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905708/how-to-decrypt-sent-binary-message-by-whatsapp-web

Answer (score 3):

Web.whatsapp.com uses web socket to communicate,

first open developer toolbar in chrome then login in web.whatsapp.com then go to network tab in developer toolbar find **WS** filter and click on it. You'll find web.whatsapp.com is connected on wss://web.whatsapp.com/ws

Comment: I think the OP wanted to capture (decrypt) the message that we see in the network monitor.