# How to decrypt sent binary message by whatsapp web

Tags: encryption, whatsapp

I am trying to decode WhatsApp web sending and receiving messages. I am able to decrypt binary messages received via websocket using `encKey` and `macKey` but not able to search a way to decrypt sent messages. I am using google chrome dev tools to copy the messages.

[image]

The ones in white are received messages and green are sent. Please explain or provide some resource where I can get this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the first two bytes from sent binary data and the rest got decrypted properly.

As per the code [here](https://github.com/shashwat001/whatsapp-web-graph/blob/863b1964ea9384d9daf202822cafec36c252c962/client.py#L180),

```
payload = bytearray(messageId) + bytearray(",") + bytearray(to_bytes(WAMetrics.MESSAGE, 1)) + bytearray(
      [0x80]) + encryptedMessage
```

The WebSocket payload to be sent is concatenation of messageid and comma followed by two bytes i.e. `bytearray(to_bytes(WAMetrics.MESSAGE, 1))` and `bytearray([0x80])` and then the encrypted message.

Considering this format, I copied payload from Google Chrome, splitted on first comma and then removed two bytes as above. The remaining binary was encrypted message which could be directly decrypted by the keys.

```
 def reverseDecryptMessage(message):
    messageSplit = message.split(",", 1)
    if len(messageSplit) == 1:
      return
    messageContent = messageSplit[1]
    messageContent = messageContent[2:]
    decryptBinary(messageContent)
```

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and explain?

Comment: Where can we find the decryptBinary function?

Comment: @baptx https://github.com/shashwat001/whatsapp-web-graph/blob/863b1964ea9384d9daf202822cafec36c252c962/client.py#L157

Comment: @ShashwatKumar thanks, it could be useful to mention in the readme file that your project is based on https://github.com/sigalor/whatsapp-web-reveng/tree/master/backend. I tried to decrypt sent and received WebSocket messages from WhatsApp Web but did not get it working (I get the "Hmac mismatch" error), do you have an idea why it fails? I just tested with Firefox since it is the only browser I allowed with QR code.
Here is the full code: https://pastebin.com/hNBeEqgv

Comment: @baptx Check if this works using python 2.7 https://pastebin.com/4eS6nAz2

Comment: @ShashwatKumar with Python 2.7, I had to add `# coding=utf-8` at the top of the fie to fix `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2'` because there were special characters in the multiline message I want to decrypt.
I also had to comment `from media import Download, DownloadParams` to fix `ImportError: No module named media`.
But with Python 2.7, I get `ImportError: No module named curve25519` even when installing curve25519-donna or curve25519 with pip2.7.
With Python 3.8, I get `AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'privateKey'`. I noticed `setConnInfoParams` is never called.

Comment: The curve25519 error was because it was not correctly installed with Python 2, I had to use `python2 -m pip install curve25519-donna` instead of using pip2 directly. But curve25519 was not needed as well as the private / public key and secret, we can directly use the encKey / macKey from localStorage. To make the decryption work, I had to use a WebSocket message intercepted with a tool like mitmproxy / mitmdump because the "Copy Message" feature from Firefox did not give the correct string. I updated my Pastebin with the full working code, the `.encode('utf-8')` that I used was not needed.